# Flutter : align center a specific child in a Row Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm a newbie in flutter and I'm trying to code a UI Instagram clone, How can I align a carousel indicator to the center with a `Row()` parent like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r39CZ.jpg)

```
Stack(
 alignment: Alignment.center,
children:[
buildIndicator(),
//Icon section
Row(
children:[
buildLeftIcons(),
buildRightIcon(),
],
),
],
),
```

Result I got:
[![final result][this]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r39CZ.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey you can use Spacer() between icons and dot in row children . Spacer widget auto take extra width like below -

```
Row(
  children: [
     Icon(),   
     Icon(),   
     Icon(),  
     Spacer(),
     DotsIndicator(),
     Spacer(), 
  ],
),
```

Here is another example with `Expanded` widget and row, Expanded will automatically take rest of width other then icons

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
         Icon(),   
         Icon(),   
         Icon(),  
         Expanded(
           child: Center(
             child: DotsIndicator(),
           )
         ),
      ],
    ),
```

// UI with left and right icons

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
         Icon(),   
         Icon(),   
         Icon(),  
         Expanded(
           child: Center(
             child: DotsIndicator(),
           )
         ),
        Icon(),  
      ],
    ),
```

For you reference  - [Spacer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html) and
[Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)

Comment: Thank you. It works. Can you explain to me how it works?

Comment: Hey @CôngHiến Expanded widget automatically take width as per it's flex, and because we are using only 1 expanded widget so it's not necessary to specify how much percent of width it should take, so here in above example  all the width will be assign to Expended apart from icons width

Comment: Hey @CôngHiến if i my answer meet your requirement, then i would appreciate if you can upvote my answer

Comment: Well when I put another Icon in the right end of Row, it has Expanded on the outside has child Align to align the Icon in the bottom right, so it combines with your suggestion perfectly,and not without it. I don't understand why?

Comment: Can you share your code what you were trying

Comment: How can I upvote for you?

Comment: How to mark it to code section in the comment ?

Comment: you can edit in your question

Comment: Hey I share my code, please review it

Comment: @CôngHiến you don’t need to use Spacer if you are using Expanded widget

Comment: @CôngHiến if you want's to align button in Right side then you can just add another icon next to Expended widget so i will automatically take available width between first 3 Icon and Right end side icon

Comment: I have updated my answer with 3 left side icons and dots in middle  and 1 right  side icon

Comment: Hi thanks for your supporting enthusiasm. I have updated my code and it fix my issue perfectly as I expected

Answer (score 0):

In the row, you can give a `SizedBox(width: )` in the range to push a specific widget a certain distance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  ///put favourite,comment,send icon here
                ],
              ),
              ///put yor indicator widget here
              Indicator(),
              ///add an empty container here
              Container()
            ],
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

It would somehow complex to do that but I have two suggestions:

1. Use `Row()`'s `MainAxisAlignment.start` then add a desired Widget in between the first widgets and the indicators to give space say like a `SizedBox(width:80.0)`
2. Separate the two widgets by using `Column()`. I prefer this since I would just add the carousel indicator as first item in the column then wrap it in a `Center()` widget, then the second widget in the column would be your desired widgets(favourite, message and comments icons)